# Prove that $f(x) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\cos(t))^x dt$ is decreasing

Tags: integration

> Consider, for $x>0$,
>    $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cos(t))^x dt$$
>   How to prove that the function $f$ is decreasing?

I guess that I have to calculate the derivative of $f$, but I don't know how to do so with such functions.

Comment: Computing the derivative is quite unnecessary. What do you know, for every fixed $t$ in $(0,\pi/2)$, about the function $$x\mapsto(\cos t)^x\ ?$$

Comment: I got it ! when $t$ is fixed $(cos t)^x$ decreases as $0 < cos (t) < 1$. Therefore, the integral also decreases

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Precisely. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate the derivative, you need the Leibniz integral rule:
$$ f'(x) =  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\cos(t))^x \,dx.$$
Next you have to show that $f'(x)$ is negative. This will follow from the fact that the integrand is negative.

Note that I haven't given you all the details. If you need more help, you're welcome to ask it in a comment.